# Neo4j Node/Relationship to Byte[]

Tags: java, serialization, neo4j, arrays

I have a StorageClass containing

```
public HashMap<Integer, Object> writeSet;
```

Key = Node/Relationship Index
Value = Node or Relationship

I have to serialize and later deserialize this HashMap to and from a Byte[].

Since Node and Relationship doesn't seem to be serializable, is it possible to convert this HashMap to a ByteArray?

Thank you already

Comment: "Node and Relationship doesn't seem to be serializable", are you sure they are not ? Additionally, can't you provide an overridden serializable implementation ? Finally, if these classes are not serializable, maybe there is a very good reason as to why. Do you have more info on what library they come from ?

Comment: why do you want to store that information, since it's redundant with what Neo4J stored and let you retrieve (you can get a node or a relationship from its ID). Assuming you want to keep the state maybe for archiving, I would suggest transforming the Neo4J objects into your own objects with only the info you need, and serialize them.

Comment: I want to store that information to recreate the exact same Object on another Neo4j Server. To send this object to this server I have to use a byte[].

Answer (score 0):

You can also just receive them as JSON or other format on the server, that's way easier.

See: http://jexp.github.io/blog/html/load_json.html

to convert a property-container into a map:

```
for (String prop : pc.getPropertyKeys()) {
  map.put(prop,pc.getProperty(prop));
}
```